# Javascript array within an array without quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build a javascript array using only values, however my data keeps getting wrapped in quotes and I don't understand how to not have that happen.

I gather I might be pushing the data as a string and not an object, though I'm not certain of how to do that and still get the result I'm after.

**My code**

```
var $coordinates = [] ;
var $newCoords = '[' + $long + ',' + $lat + ']' ;
$coordinates.push( $newCoords ) ;
```

**Expected result**

```
[[52.7718663,-1.1964961], [52.7704243,-1.1960509], [52.7702679,-1.1958254], [52.7717278,-1.1961103], [52.7705612,-1.1957975], [52.7710724,-1.1958186], [52.7721671,-1.1964786], [52.7704262,-1.1959578], [52.8963141,-1.2654371], [52.8963454,-1.2652917], [52.8963452,-1.2652924], [52.8028284,-1.6005342], [52.9819934,-1.4555365], [52.7702942,-1.1959922]]
```

**Actual result**

```
"[52.7718663,-1.1964961]", "[52.7704243,-1.1960509]", "[52.7702679,-1.1958254]", "[52.7717278,-1.1961103]", "[52.7705612,-1.1957975]", "[52.7710724,-1.1958186]", "[52.7721671,-1.1964786]", "[52.7704262,-1.1959578]", "[52.8963141,-1.2654371]", "[52.8963454,-1.2652917]", "[52.8963452,-1.2652924]", "[52.8028284,-1.6005342]", "[52.9819934,-1.4555365]", "[52.7702942,-1.1959922]"]
```

Comment: `'[' + $long + ',' + $lat + ']' ;` it's not an array but a string.

Comment: Why are you starting variables with `$`? Javascript isn't PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use the quotes. If you use

```
var $coordinates = [] ;
var $newCoords = [$long, $lat];
$coordinates.push( $newCoords ) ;
```

You'll be fine.

**Edit**: Adding off of Aloso's point, <strike>you shouldn't</strike> it isn't the best practice to start variables with the `$` in javascript, so I'd really recommend using

```
var coordinates = [] ;
var newCoords = [long, lat];
coordinates.push( newCoords ) ;
```

for your code.

Comment: why shouldn't variables start with `$`? It's perfectly valid although most would use it for special circumstances/conventions

Comment: I mean it's technically alright, but it can mess with libraries and such and just isn't considered good style.

Comment: Then say that...don't imply there is anything wrong with it when it is valid. I use it all the time to denote jQuery objects and is very common practice there

Comment: That's the reason why its use is discouraged in basic javascript, because it is used in jQuery, etc.

Comment: You are confusing starting variable name with the global `$` object. Not same thing...it;s just a variable name